# Result from web api in Json Format should return specific data only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables:

Student (StudentId, StudentName, ClassId)

Class (ClassId, ClassName)

When I call Web Api to fetch record of a student then it return the student and all others students associated with that class.

While I want to just get the record of one student having the class.

I have used Entity Framework in it.

It is possible to get accurate result while making another modelView. But don't want to make another model.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
    {
        Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(student);
    }
```

I am getting result like in Json

```
"Class": {
"Students": [
  {
    "StudentId": 12,
    "StudentName": "Ahtasham Ul Haq",
    "ClassId": 2
  },
  {
    "StudentId": 14,
    "StudentName": "Waseem Akram",
    "ClassId": 2
  }
],
"ClassId": 2,
"ClassName": "MCS"
},
"StudentId": 5,
"StudentName": "Basit Ali"
"ClassId": 2
```

But Ш want to get result of Student having the id 5 and not for 12 and 14.

Comment: Looking at the json is a little bit confusing. Are the ones not in code-text included?, if yes the show the student class

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the response you posted and the controller action shown, I'm guessing you have a navigation property for `Class` in your `Student` as well that isn't mentioned in your post. You can only return the student details with no associated child data by replacing `Find` with `SingleOrDefault`. With `SingleOrDefault`, if you ever want to include related entities, you'll need to specifically `.Include` them otherwise you will only be returned data for the specified entity.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
{
    Student student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentId == id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(student);
}
```